# Regex For Getting A Value Between 2 Dynamic Values? VB.NET

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am trying to get the value shown in the string below:

```
"data_one:": false, "data_two": "RANDOM_STRING", "id": "NEED_TO_GET"
```

Note that I cannot simply obtain "id": "value" as there are many many different "id" fields on the page so I thought I may be able to get this with the following Regex expressions but no luck:

```
"data_one": false, "data_two": (.+?), "id": "(.+?)"
```

I am still getting to grips with Regex so could do with a but of a hand getting this right to understand how it all works!

So my VB.NET Function is:

```
Public Function GetAllStringsBetween(ByVal Haystack As String, ByVal StartSearch As String, ByVal EndSearch As String) As String()
        Dim rx As New Regex(StartSearch & "(.+?)" & EndSearch)
        Dim mc As MatchCollection = rx.Matches(Haystack.Trim())
        Dim FoundStrings(mc.Count) As String
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        For Each m As Match In mc
            FoundStrings(i) = m.Groups(1).Value.ToString()
            i += 1
        Next
        Return FoundStrings
    End Function
```

& I am calling with:

```
Dim ScrapedInfo() As String = GetAllStringsBetween(HTML_Content, """data_one"": false, ""data_two"": (.+?), ""id"": """, """")
```

Comment: It's unclear which part you're trying to get.  Can you edit to make it more clear?  Also, is that an abstracted version of the string, or does it literally have colons and quotes, etc?

Comment: Thanks, Updated the Q. The data is JSON so it does include the quotes.

Comment: if it's well formed JSON, why not use a parser?  Or is nothing available for VB?

Comment: I have not found anything decent in VB / for the sake of needing it once I do not want to integrate one of the large classes, I have a workaround of getting the first string & then scraping the second, just thought that it may have been possible using Regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure if you're after `RANDOM_STRING` or `NEED_TO_GET`, but

`:\s"([A-Za-z]*)",` will match the first one, and
`:\s"([A-Za-z]*)"$`
will match the second one.

Those are generic regex expressions, you'll need to see what the specific requirements for VB style are (what characters to enclose it with, etc.)

In Perl, the part inside the parenthesis would be accessible via `$1`, but I don't know how that works in VB.

You can take advantage of the fact that they are both preceded by a colon, a space, and a double-quote, i.e. `:\s"`